# How to Create and Bind the Grid for Display With Quintuple Nested Lists C# ASP.net .aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I'm working on a project where it is necessary for me to create and bind the grid to display a response from a server which is a list of classes and some fields, the lists of classes also contain some variables as well as another list of a different class which contains some fields and another list of a different class...and goes on for five levels.

I must display the top level class and all of the lists of classes as well as each of the nested lists within the list and by itself. Allow me to use pseudocode to try to better explain with a triple tier. I am dealing with a quintuple tier.

```
classA
{
List<classB> classBList;
List<classC> classCList;
int whatever;
string something;
}

ClassB
{
List<classC> classCList;
int somethingElse;
string otherThing;
}

classC
{
int somethingA;
string somethingB;
}

List<ClassA> list1;
```

I am trying to create and bind and display the grid for list1. I've mainly been a straight back end coder so the .aspx page is what is really throwing me for a loop. I've figured out how bind and display with fields and fields within classes and a single list, but these lists are really challenging for me and I haven't made any progress in a couple of days.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like where you flatten all the values down and use a dictionary to track their origin (if it's needed). You would then have a flattened list of all values, and could easily create or recreate an original list of values (those belonging to ClassA.ClassBList, for example) using Linq or the Dictionary keys themselves:

```
public class flattenedList
{
    public string whatever;
    public int whateverInt;
}
public class nested
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<flattenedList>> listData = new Dictionary<string, List<flattenedList>>();
    private List<ClassA> list1 = new List<ClassA>();
    ClassA classA = new ClassA();
    ClassB classB = new ClassB();
    ClassC classC = new ClassC();
    public void processCalsses()
    {
        string key = "";
        foreach (ClassA a in list1)
        {
            key = "ClassA.ClassBList";
            foreach (ClassB b in classA.classBList)
            {
                addToDictionary(key, new flattenedList() { whatever = b.otherThing, whateverInt = b.somethingElse });
            }
            key = "ClassA.ClassCList";
            foreach (ClassC c in classA.classCList)
            {
                addToDictionary(key, new flattenedList() { whatever = c.somethingB, whateverInt = c.somethingA });
            }
            addToDictionary("ClassA", new flattenedList() { whatever = a.something, whateverInt = a.whatever });
        }
        key = "ClassB.ClassCList";
        foreach (ClassC c in classB.classCList)
        {
            addToDictionary(key, new flattenedList() { whatever = c.somethingB, whateverInt = c.somethingA });
        }
        addToDictionary("ClassB", new flattenedList() { whatever = classB.otherThing, whateverInt = classB.somethingElse });
        addToDictionary("ClassC", new flattenedList() { whatever = classC.somethingB, whateverInt = classC.somethingA });
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<flattenedList>> kvp in listData)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < kvp.Value.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key + "[" + i.ToString() + "] whatever = " + kvp.Value[i].whatever);
                Console.WriteLine(key + "[" + i.ToString() + "] whateverInt = " + kvp.Value[i].whateverInt.ToString() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    private void addToDictionary(string key, flattenedList f)
    {
        if (!listData.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            listData.Add(key, new List<flattenedList>());
        }
        listData[key].Add(f);
    }
    public class ClassA
    {
        public List<ClassB> classBList = new List<ClassB>();
        public List<ClassC> classCList;
        public int whatever;
        public string something;
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public List<ClassC> classCList;
        public int somethingElse;
        public string otherThing;
    }

    public class ClassC
    {
        public int somethingA;
        public string somethingB;
    }


}
```

Note that I had to instantiate the classes in order to get the intellisense to let me type. I assume you'd create instance versions visible to this method either within class scope or within a public static class.

PS - if you don't need to maintain the origin of each datum (which class and list it came from), then there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: Thanks Shannon, I'll check it.  Much appreciated!